# create strings using combinations of list items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I like to create strings in the following manner:
The string has a prefix, a main part and a suffix, all separated by a delimiter.
The prefixes, suffixes and delimiters are stored in lists

```
ListOfPrefixes=['pre1','pre2']
ListOfSuffixes=['suf1','suf2','suf3']
ListOfDelims=['-','_','']
MainPart = 'main'
```

Now I like to create strings using combinations of the list items like

```
pre1-main-suf1
pre2-main-suf1
pre1-main-suf2
...
pre2_main_suf2
...
pre1mainsuf3
```

I tried to use itertools to get combinations of the list items, but I didn't find the correct code to get my combinatons.

Is there an easy way or do I have to combine several itertools.combinations? Or do I have to loop over all lists?

Comment: can you add the code you tried

Comment: I for got to mention one thing: I need strings of the form pre1_pre2_main_suf1_suf2, too. So the combination of of prefixes +main pat+combination of suffixes

Comment: Now that's a very different problem…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools
for pre, suf, sep in itertools.product(ListOfPrefixes, ListOfSuffixes, ListOfDelims):
    print(sep.join([pre, MainPart, suf])
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thats it: if I define .product(ListOfPrefixex,ListOfPrefixes,ListOfSuffixes,ListOfSuffixes,ListOfDelims) I get all my needed combinations!

Comment: In this case, of course, you need to change to `pre1, pre2, suf1, suf2` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`combinations` returns n-length combinations without replacement from a single sequence e.g. all pairs from (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) would be (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), ..., (3, 4).

That's not what you want at all here, **what you're looking for is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)**, you give it any number of iterables and it returns tuples of that size with one item picked from each iterable (enumerating all possibilities).

```py
def the_thing(main_part, prefixes, delimiters, suffixes):
    for pre, sep, suf in product(prefixes, delimiters, suffixes):
        print(sep.join([pre, main_part, suf])
```

Comment: I like the `sep.join` part, very nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop and iterate through each of the prefixes, suffixes and delimiters then concatenate like this.

EDIT: if you want the extra combinations from your updated comment, you can just add more nests to the loop and add a condition to check if the first and second prefix or first and second suffix are the same if you dont want them:

```
ListOfPrefixes=['pre1','pre2']
ListOfSuffixes=['suf1','suf2','suf3']
ListOfDelims=['-','_','']
MainPart = 'main'


for prefix in ListOfPrefixes:
    for suffix in ListOfSuffixes:
        for delimiter in ListOfDelims:
            for prefix2 in ListOfPrefixes:
                for suffix2 in ListOfSuffixes:
                    if prefix != prefix2 and suffix != suffix2:
                        print(prefix + delimiter + prefix2 + delimiter + MainPart + delimiter + suffix + delimiter + suffix2)

#and a second nested loop for the rest:

for prefix in ListOfPrefixes:
    for suffix in ListOfSuffixes:
        for delimiter in ListOfDelims:
            print(prefix + delimiter + MainPart + delimiter + suffix)
```

Output:

```
pre1-pre2-main-suf1-suf2
pre1-pre2-main-suf1-suf3
pre1_pre2_main_suf1_suf2
pre1_pre2_main_suf1_suf3
pre1pre2mainsuf1suf2
pre1pre2mainsuf1suf3
pre1-pre2-main-suf2-suf1
pre1-pre2-main-suf2-suf3
pre1_pre2_main_suf2_suf1
pre1_pre2_main_suf2_suf3
pre1pre2mainsuf2suf1
pre1pre2mainsuf2suf3
pre1-pre2-main-suf3-suf1
pre1-pre2-main-suf3-suf2
pre1_pre2_main_suf3_suf1
pre1_pre2_main_suf3_suf2
pre1pre2mainsuf3suf1
pre1pre2mainsuf3suf2
pre2-pre1-main-suf1-suf2
pre2-pre1-main-suf1-suf3
pre2_pre1_main_suf1_suf2
pre2_pre1_main_suf1_suf3
pre2pre1mainsuf1suf2
pre2pre1mainsuf1suf3
pre2-pre1-main-suf2-suf1
pre2-pre1-main-suf2-suf3
pre2_pre1_main_suf2_suf1
pre2_pre1_main_suf2_suf3
pre2pre1mainsuf2suf1
pre2pre1mainsuf2suf3
pre2-pre1-main-suf3-suf1
pre2-pre1-main-suf3-suf2
pre2_pre1_main_suf3_suf1
pre2_pre1_main_suf3_suf2
pre2pre1mainsuf3suf1
pre2pre1mainsuf3suf2
pre1-main-suf1
pre1_main_suf1
pre1mainsuf1
pre1-main-suf2
pre1_main_suf2
pre1mainsuf2
pre1-main-suf3
pre1_main_suf3
pre1mainsuf3
pre2-main-suf1
pre2_main_suf1
pre2mainsuf1
pre2-main-suf2
pre2_main_suf2
pre2mainsuf2
pre2-main-suf3
pre2_main_suf3
pre2mainsuf3
```

Storing the combinations in a list is useful when doing this method. If you have redundant data within the list of combinations you can use this trick:

```
combinationList = list(dict.fromkeys(combinationList))
```

Doing this will convert it to a dictionary then back to a list, removing the unwanted duplicates (if u have any).

Answer (score 0):

You want a cartesian product.

```
from itertools import product

[f"{p}{d}{MainPart}{d}{s}" for d, s, p in
 product(ListOfDelims, ListOfSuffixes, ListOfPrefixes)]
```

Pretty-printed this is

```
['pre1-main-suf1',
 'pre2-main-suf1',
 'pre1-main-suf2',
 'pre2-main-suf2',
 'pre1-main-suf3',
 'pre2-main-suf3',
 'pre1_main_suf1',
 'pre2_main_suf1',
 'pre1_main_suf2',
 'pre2_main_suf2',
 'pre1_main_suf3',
 'pre2_main_suf3',
 'pre1mainsuf1',
 'pre2mainsuf1',
 'pre1mainsuf2',
 'pre2mainsuf2',
 'pre1mainsuf3',
 'pre2mainsuf3']
```

A Cartesian product works like nested for loops. You didn't want the delimiters in the same string to differ, even though you used them twice, so I repeated them in the f-string, not in the product.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

ListOfPrefixes=['pre1','pre2']
MainPart = ['main']
ListOfSuffixes=['suf1','suf2','suf3']
ListOfDelims=['-','_','']


FullList = [ListOfPrefixes, MainPart, ListOfSuffixes]

for x in list(itertools.product(*FullList)):
    for i in range(len(ListOfDelims)):
        print(ListOfDelims[i].join(x))
```

output:

```
pre1-main-suf1
pre1_main_suf1
pre1mainsuf1
pre1-main-suf2
pre1_main_suf2
pre1mainsuf2
pre1-main-suf3
pre1_main_suf3
pre1mainsuf3
pre2-main-suf1
pre2_main_suf1
pre2mainsuf1
pre2-main-suf2
pre2_main_suf2
pre2mainsuf2
pre2-main-suf3
pre2_main_suf3
pre2mainsuf3
```